# Reversing an integer

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to write a function which takes an input number and outputs the number in reverse order.

Ie:

Input -> 25
Output -> 52

Input -> 125
Output -> 521

I am new to lisp, if its helpful here is the working function in c++

**function.cpp**

```
int revs(int rev, int n)
{
  if (n <= 0)
    return rev;

  return revs((rev * 10) + (n % 10), n/10);
}
```

I have written it in Racket as follows:

```
(define (revs rev n)
  (if (<= n 0)
     rev
     (revs (+ (* rev 10) (modulo n 10)) (/ n 10))))
```

But when I run it with (revs 0 125) I get this error:

```
modulo: contract violation
  expected: integer?
  given: 25/2
  argument position: 1st
  other arguments...:
   10
```

Certainly I am doing something incorrect here, but I am unsure of what I am missing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The division operator `/` doesn't do integer division, but general division, so when you call, e.g., `(/ 25 2)`, you don't get `12` or `13`, but rather the rational `25/2`.  I think you'd want [`quotient`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._quotient%29%29) instead, about which the documentation has:

> ```
> procedure (quotient n m) → integer?  
>   n : integer?   
>   m : integer?
> ```
>
> Returns `(truncate (/ n m))`. Examples:
>
> ```
> > (quotient 10 3)
> 3
> > (quotient -10.0 3)
> -3.0
> > (quotient +inf.0 3)
> quotient: contract violation  
>   expected: integer?   
>   given: +inf.0  
>   argument position: 1st
>   other arguments...:
>    3
> ```

Comment: thanks, quotient works. Also taking the floor of the division worked as well, but may not be the best approach.

Comment: @r-s as the documentation says, it's equivalent to `(truncate (/ n m))` which, as you say, it like taking the floor of the division.  The difference is that `floor` returns a real, whereas `truncate` returns an integer.

Answer (score 5):

Treating the operation lexicographically:

```
#lang racket
(define (lexicographic-reverse  x)
  (string->number
   (list->string
    (reverse
     (string->list
      (number->string x))))))
```

Works[1] for any of Racket's numerical types.

---

[edit 1] "Works," I realized, is context dependent and with a bit of testing shows the implicit assumptions of the operation. My naive lexicographic approach makes a mess of negative integers, e.g. `(lexicographic-reverse -47)` will produce an error.

However, getting an error rather than `-74` might be better when if I am reversing numbers for lexicographic reasons rather than numerical ones because it illuminates the fact that the definition of "reversing a number" is arbitrary. The reverse of 47 could just as well be -74 as 74 because reversing is not a mathematical concept - even though it might remind me of XOR  permutation.

How the sign is handled is by a particular reversing function is arbitrary.

```
#lang racket

;; Reversing a number retains the sign
(define (arbitrary1  x) 
  (define (f n)
    (string->number
     (list->string
      (reverse
       (string->list
        (number->string n))))))
  (if (>= x 0)
      (f x)
      (- (f (abs x)))))

;; Reversing a number reverses the sign
(define (arbitrary2  x)
  (define (f n)
    (string->number
     (list->string
      (reverse
       (string->list
        (number->string n))))))
  (if (>= x 0)
      (- (f x))
      (f (abs x))))
```

The same considerations extend to Racket's other numerical type notations; decisions about reversing exact, inexact, complex, are likewise arbitrary - e.g. what is the reverse of IEEE `+inf.0` or `+nan.0`?

Comment: Ooh, I need to steal this as an example for the so-called threading macro. :)  `(~> x number->string string->list reverse list->string string->number)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution for this problem

```
(define (reverseInt number)
  (define (loop number reversedNumber)
    (if (= number 0)
        reversedNumber
        (let ((lastDigit (modulo number 10)))
          (loop (/ (- number lastDigit) 10) (+ (* reversedNumber 10) lastDigit)))))
  (loop number 0))
```

Each time we multiply the reversed number by 10 and add the last digit of number.

I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

A R6RS version (will work with R7RS with a little effort)

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs)
        (srfi :8))

(define (numeric-reverse n)
  (let loop ((acc 0) (n n))
    (if (zero? n)
        acc
        (receive (q r) (div-and-mod n 10)
          (loop (+ (* acc 10) r) q)))))
```

A Racket implementation:

```
#!racket
(require srfi/8)

(define (numeric-reverse n)
  (let loop ((acc 0) (n n))
    (if (zero? n)
        acc
        (receive (q r) (quotient/remainder n 10)
          (loop (+ (* acc 10) r) q)))))
```

Comment: For the lexicographic reverse, `(require srfi/13)` provides the function `string-reverse` to Racket.

Answer (score 0):

With recursion, you can do something like:

```lisp
#lang racket

(define (reverse-num n)
  (let f ([acc 0]
          [n n])
    (cond
      [(zero? n) acc]
      [else (f (+ (* acc 10) (modulo n 10)) (quotient n 10))])))
```